# Which Libraries are included in PHP?

Tags: php, installation, default

Are there Libraries which are in every present PHP installation?

An Example:

I'm using cURL in a PHP Script, does it run on every PHP installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libraries like cURL aren't in a default PHP installation. Though most hosts do carry a default set of extensions which have been widely used, which usually include cURL.

PHP has a page on which it's built-in functions which will most likely explain this further: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.internal.php

There's also a page with function references to find the most used libraries that can be installed using PEAR: https://www.php.net/manual/en/funcref.php

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question but didn't find the answer. So I try to find default php libraries by install a new php-fpm7.1 (install your php version that you want to see it's libraries) then run command `php -m` the result:

`calendar Core ctype date exif fileinfo filter ftp gettext hash iconv json libxml openssl pcntl pcre PDO Phar posix readline Reflection session shmop sockets SPL standard sysvmsg sysvsem sysvshm tokenizer Zend OPcache zlib`